# How to parse JMeter test report in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

I am using JMeter do API test, and also integrated with CI tool Jenkins.
Now I want to parse the JMeter test report in Jenkins. But I don't need performance test report.

I need the report to list total number of cases, how many cases passed and how many cases failed.

Anyone have this solution?

Answer (score 2):

JMeter was designed for performance testing, and the world of performance testing still heavily relies on human interpretation of test results. Therefore "case" or "test" is not natively supported by JMeter. However, you group your requests under transaction controller(s) and use "generate parent sample" option. This should make the transaction controller and all requests it groups effectively a "test" and either pass or fail it as a whole.

Now, the other question is how to get number of executed and failed "tests". Currently jmeter-maven-plugin can provide information about number of JMX files processed and number of failed "cases". I doesn't provide information about total number of "cases" which were exected. There is a [pull request](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/pull/132) opened which will improve it - reports will contain number of JMX files processed, total number of tests executed and number of failed tests.

**EDIT**

The functionality you are looking for is currently provided by [Lightning](https://github.com/automatictester/lightning/wiki/Usage-Example#report-mode). It will parse JMeter output and report total number of transactions and number of failed transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Performance Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin).
Also you could save execution log file, download it after test execution and open it in some JMeter listener (e.g. Summary report). There you will see all the report data:

```
export OUTPUT=/jenkins/userContent/Load_tests

jmeter -t testscript.jmx -l $OUTPUT/results.jtl
echo "Download a log file http://<url of your Jenkins>/userContent/Load_tests/results.jtl"
```